# How to retrieve custom fields in the remote SDP attributes?

Tags: android, bluetooth

In addition to UUID, it is perfectly fine to have custom key values in the attributes of the SDP record. For instance

```
<attribute id="0x0100">
    <uuid value="0x1101" />
    <text value="I am a home made BT board" />
</attribute>
```

is valid. Actually we don't even need to provide an UUID if we are not interested in exchanging further information with the remote device.

In my case, I just want to be able to retrieve the different fields of the SDP record of a remote bluetooth device. Say I want to have something like `retrieve_SDP_attribute(uuid UUID)` that would return the xml code shown above. Or even better, a dictionary.

I could find [`getUuids()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getUuids()) for Android but this does only the job of retrieving the UUID, however I am interested in custom fields as well.